# Flash data message is not getting displayed in the view

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am trying to set flash data in Controller 1 and redirect to Controller 2, where I store the data in a `$page_data` variable to get it displayed in View 2. The following are my codes:

#### Controller 1:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message','my custom message');
  redirect('controller2','refresh');
```

#### Controller 2:

```
 $page_data['loginmessage'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
 $this->load->view('view2',$page_data);
```

#### View 2:

```
<p> <?php echo $loginmessage ?> </p>
```

CodeIgniter is able to load View 2, but  does not display the login message. To put in another way, I am not getting the flash data message in Controller 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the small piece of code your code to redirect it correctly.

Controller 1:

```
function first()
{
$this->session->set_flashdata('message','my custom message');
redirect("/controller2/second", "refresh");
}
```

Controller 2:

```
function second()
{
$page_data['loginmessage'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
$this->load->view('view2',$page_data);
}
```

Also, if you refresh the page then flash data will disappear because it will appear only once.

View code is same

```
<p> <?php echo $loginmessage ?> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use controller 2 for showing flashdata. Use this

Controller1

```
  $this->session->set_flashdata('message','my custom message');
  redirect('controller2/any_method');
```

Now you may use `message` in `view2.php` (which you are loading through controller 2) file as

```
<p> <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?> </p>
```